# Can't Access XML form Main Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, windows, android-layout, kotlin

I cannot access the elements in my XML form the main activity,
writing the element id throws errors as if the element is not even there.
Basically Main can't see what is written in XML file, even though they are linked.

[Can't detect the getBmiButton button from XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKWjm.png)

[Button was defined here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yko2.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you Don't need findViewById() anymore.
You should Integrate Kotlin Android Extensions by adding these lines to build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and use your view as a property. If you are curious how this works, [this article](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To access the XML view's Identifiers directly into the code, you can choose among `DataBindinng`, `ViewBinding` or `Kotlin Extensions` dependencies but currently, you're not using any one of these. By default, `R.java` is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory.

you can access the identifiers as follow:

```
val button = findViewById(R.id.getBmiButton) as Button
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Build drop down menu in the menu bar. you can see the Rebuild Project under the Clean Project. Rebuild project cleans the project actually. If you cant find Rebuild Project you can simply use Clean Project.

Answer (score -1):

```
button = findViewById(R.id.getBmiButton) as Button;
```

visit [here](https://quiro.dev/posts/improving-findViewById-kotlin/)